# How to get subcategories in category.php NOT posts

Tags: wordpress, categories

Is there any way to get only subcategories in `category.php` file instead of posts?

I know that WordPress paginates `category.php` by doing its own query and that I should not create a new query, but I need to show only the child categories in some categories instead of posts.

**And, because I have many, I also need it to be paginated**...

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try below code:

```
$args = array('child_of' => get_query_var('cat') );
$categories = get_categories( $args );

$numOfItems = 2; // Set no of category per page
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$to = $page * $numOfItems;
$current = $to - $numOfItems;
$total = sizeof( $categories );

echo '<ul class="content">';
    for( $i=$current; $i<$to; ++$i ) {
        $category = $categories[$i];
        if( $category->name ) { 
            echo '<li>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></li>';
        }
    }
echo '</ul>';

unset( $category );

/* For pagination */
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'total' => ceil($total / $numOfItems),
    'current' => $page
));
```

**This code is tested and working perfect.**

Comment: Why didn't you read the question first? If I could, I would mark this as not useful! This will NOT WORK like I need! If I paste this on category.php, wordpress will calculate the number of pages by the posts published on it, not the child categories. I need to show only subcategories (NOT POSTS) in some categories.

Comment: You didn't read the question part: **"And, because I have many, I also need it to be paginated..."**! This is not useful!!!

Comment: **No good!** This replaces wordpress regular pagination, and if you use a SEO plugin, it will alter the `rel="canonical"`,`rel="next"` and `rel="previous"` tags hurting the site.

Comment: No need to add that tag in link as SEO use that tags. see WordPress Core ticket https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24375